# ClojureScript cljs.core.async/go doesn't work inside jsdom

Tags: asynchronous, karma-runner, clojurescript, jsdom, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I am trying to migrate ClojureScript tests from "Chrome Headless" to [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) using [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html) and [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs) as test runners.

The regular tests which require access to DOM or browser API work fine. But async test where `cljs.core.async/go` is used doesn't work. Basically, nothing inside `go` is executed.

Does anyone have some idea what could be wrong? Did I miss some configuration? Is it only `jsdom` issue or maybe it is `cljs.core.async` interoperability issue?

I have put a simple test example below

```
(ns async-tests
  (:require [cljs.test :refer [deftest async]]
            [cljs.core.async :refer [go <! timeout]]))

(deftest async-go-test
  (async done
    (.log js/console "Before go is printed")
    (go
      (.log js/console "After go is never printed")
      (<! (timeout 1))
      (done))))
```

The result I get in console is

```
LOG: 'Testing async-tests'
LOG: 'Before go is printed'
WebKit 537.36 (undefined 0.0.0): Executed 159 of 185 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.589 secs)
WebKit 537.36 (undefined 0.0.0) ERROR
Disconnected, because no message in 30000 ms.
```

Versions of libraries which are used:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-cljs-test": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-jsdom-launcher": "^8.0.2",
    "shadow-cljs": "2.10.19"
  }
```

Karma configuration:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['jsdom'],
        basePath: 'target',
        files: ['ci.js'],
        frameworks: ['cljs-test'],
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        client: {
            args: ["shadow.test.karma.init"]
        },
        jsdomLauncher: {
            jsdom: {
                resources: "usable",
                runScripts: "dangerously",
                pretendToBeVisual: true
            }
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to say "Thank you" to the Clojure community which helped me find a workaround for this issue and especially @thheller.
The root cause is not found yet but probably that it is the result of using the
range of different libraries.

## Workaround

You have to override `goog.async.nextTick` method for your tests with
`js/setTimeout`

### Example

Create `jsdom-setup` namespace

```
(ns jsdom-setup)

(set! (.. js/window -goog -async -nextTick) js/setTimeout)
```

and add it to the tests JS output inside 'shadow-cljs.edn'

```clj
:builds {:karma {:target :karma
                 :output-to  "output/tests-bundle.js"
                 :ns-regexp "(setup-jsdom|[.-]tests$)"}}
```

## Links

[Clojure Slack discussion](https://clojurians.slack.com/archives/C03S1L9DN/p1610377230261200)

Comment: Using the solution mentioned here results in "TypeError TypeError: Illegal invocation" when I call `js/goog.async.nextTick` right after. Using ` [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.11.60"]`. I think the problem is we need to `bind` the fn to the correct `this` value? Perhaps this solution used to work due to something in closure being less strict?